# how to use vhosts with express

Tags: node.js, express

I have the following code to setup two hosts on my local computer:

```
var express = require('express');

var app1 = express.createServer()
  , app2 = express.createServer()
  , main = express.createServer()

main.use(express.vhost('api.localhost:8000', app1)
    .use(express.vhost('localhost:8000', app2))
```

When I navigate to each of those endpoints, I get 404'd. What's up with that?

Answer (score 1):

You should specify some routes on the respective servers. Something like:

```
app1.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send("welcome to app1!");
});

app2.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.send("welcome to app2!");
});
```

Also, I don't think the port number is supposed to be part of the `hostname`. Try with `api.localhost` and `localhost`, respectively.